# normalizing and scaling are different?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, dataset, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

This is the original data histogram, I have a data set and plot by DataFrame.hist():

[image: original data histogram]

After that I applied the zscore function to my data set and plot this histogram:

[image]

After I have applied zscore, I applied standardscaler to my data set and plot this:

[image]

I have some questions:

1. Why didn't my data distribution change?
2. Why didn't the standard scaler work?
3. Should I apply both a normalizing function and scaling function?

Answer (score 1):

Neither min-max scaling, nor $z$-scaling change the shape of the distribution. They do what you see on the plots, scale the values ($x$-axis), where with min-max scaling they scale them to have fixed minimum and maximum, while in $z$-scaling to have mean equal to zero and standard deviation equal to one. More than this, the scalings [don't even change the relations between the variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16710/does-standardising-independent-variables-reduce-collinearity/315089#315089). They *just* scale them.

Doing both min-max scaling and $z$-scaling makes no sense, because they [cancel out each other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318170/min-max-scaling-on-z-score-standardizd-data/318622#318622). Pick the one that is the most appropriate.

Comment: thank you for your tips but how can i change my distribution of data

Comment: @arsalangame what for..?

Comment: to normalize data

Comment: @arsalangame what for..?

Comment: @arsalangame do you think that variables need to have a normal distribution before performing an analysis like linear regression? That's a common misperception, perhaps arising from some ways of teaching regression that start with correlations among normally distributed variables. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86835/28500) among [many others on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=normality%20assumption%20linear%20regression), for why that's not necessary.